# Multiple initializers in a Go if statement

Tags: initialization, go

Just discovered Go, and am very curious so far.
I know I'm just being lazy, but I want to know if it is possible to initialize multiple variables in an if statement. I know that the following is possible:

```
if x := 5; x == 5 {
    fmt.Printf("Whee!\n")
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
if x := 5, y := 38; x == 5 {
    fmt.Printf("Whee! %d\n", y)
}

if x := 5 && y := 38; x == 5 {
    fmt.Printf("Whee! %d\n", y)
}
```

But neither worked. I looked over the documentation on the Go website, so is there anything I am missing or is this simply not possible?

Comment: This answer might be improved by giving the error messages you get when 'neither worked'. That way people are more likely to find it when googling the errors they get when they do the same thing. For me, I get `syntax error: a, _ := some.FunctionCall(x, y) used as value`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    if x, y := 5, 38; x == 5 {
        fmt.Printf("Whee! %d\n", y)
    }
}
```

Tested with this revision:

> ```
> changeset:   3975:b51fd2d6c160
> tag:         tip
> user:        Kevin Ballard <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
> date:        Tue Nov 10 20:05:24 2009 -0800
> summary:     Implement new emacs command M-x gofmt
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
package main
import("fmt")
func main() {
    if x, y := 5, 38; x == 5 {
        fmt.Printf("y = %d\n", y)
        fmt.Printf("x = %d\n", x)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Sbv6hUmKyA